# How many shortest paths are there in a brick wall

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, contest-math

This is one of the Austrian math competition questions which I am quite sure about.

From the top-left corner of this brick wall to the bottom-right corner, how many shortest paths are there? (One can only follow the white line)

Note that there are 18 rows of bricks, each with 7 whole bricks and one half-brick in an
alternating pattern.

My attempt: I know that for this type of questions, it is somehow corresponding to a sequence of R and D, but I am not sure about the details.

[image]

Comment: Are you allowed to along the left edge of the wall? That is, is it legal to go (Right, Down, Left, Down, …)? I guess not, since there is no white in that part of the picture, but it is unclear.

Comment: I am also puzzled by this. I think, as it is asking for the shortest path (i.e., to reach "finish" as quickly as possible, one needs 18 downs, but that means one has to go left twice (otherwise one cannot reach finish).

Comment: I understand you need to go left sometimes. My question is, is [this move](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFCkY.png) legal?

Comment: @MikeEarnest, the move you marked is not legal, as there is no white path on the left.

Answer (score 1):

**Big hint**

There are two types of vertices where three white segments meet; locally, they either look like $\perp$ or $\top$. Let us restrict our attention to vertices of type $\top$. The resulting picture has the connectivity of a hexagonal lattice:

```
  T   T   T   T   T   T   T
    T   T   T   T   T   T   T
  T   T   T   T   T   T   T
    T   T   T   T   T   T   T

...

  T   T   T   T   T   T   T
    T   T   T   T   T   T   T
```

From each `T`, it seems like there are three available options; you can go down and left, down and right, or move directly to the right. However, it turns out that moving directly right is inefficient, so the shortest path is made of down-right and down-left moves only.

Calling these moves $L$ and $R$, each path is a sequence of $16$ $R$'s and $2$ $L$'s. Naively, it seems like the number of paths should be $\binom{18}{2}$. However, some of these paths are illegal. Namely, you need to subtract out paths which start with and $L$, and also subtract paths which end with an $L$. Finally, paths that start with $RLL$ or end with $LLR$ are also illegal. So, you just need to count the number of bad paths. This number is relatively small, and easy to do case by case.